# DateTime formatting from msaccess to c#

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

I am probably missing something here.
I want to format a DateTime object I retrieve from access (through a tableadapter)into a C# Date object without the time part.
Here is my code:

```
textBox3.Text = table.Rows[1]["DataCreazione"].ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

This doesn't work, but if I run the following code I get a System.DateTime response.

```
textBox3.Text = table.Rows[1]["DataCreazione"].GetType();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are right, a mistake in the copy paste, the double quotes were in the running code tough!

Comment: What do you mean by "This doesn't work".  Does it throw an exception?  If so what does it say?  Does it give an unexpected result?  If so what?

Comment: There's no such thing as "a C# Date object without the time part". When you format a value, that creates a string - no more, no less.

Comment: It doesn't load, I get a "no overload method for ToString() takes 1 argument

Comment: That would be because you're working with an `object` reference and `object` doesn't have an overload for `ToString` that takes a format argument.  You'd have to cast to `DateTime` first then you could call `ToString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing a cast to `DateTime`:

```
textBox3.Text = ((DateTime)table.Rows[1]["DataCreazione"]).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I'm a noob in c#!